# Positioning issue with relative div-boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

MY issue is simple.
I have a header-box with 3 divs inside;

- A background image (relative)
- a overlay; background-color with opacity (relative)
- and a text.

The issue is that i can't position my text in the middle;
I created a javascript function handeling the issue, but the script doesn't do anything
The only way to set the top, left value for the element is to write it into the css file.

Any guesses? (And no the JS / JQuery code did work; tested it without the div-boxing madness)

Here are the files:

Index.html:

```
<head>

    <title> Website </title 


    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontboxes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">

    <!-- jQuery Einbindung -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        function adjust() {

            getElementById("mediumfontbox").style.top = 125;

        }


    </script>


</head>


<body>

    <header>
        <img src="img/header1.jpg"> </img>
        <div id="overlay1"></div>

        <div class="mediumfontbox" onload="adjust()"> Inspirational Quote </div>
    </header>


    <div class="main"></div>


    <footer id="overlay1">
        <div id="copy">Copyright by Vancold</div>
    </footer>   

</body>
```

header.css

```
header 
{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

header > * 
{
   position:absolute;
}

img 
{
   z-index: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   top: 0px; left:0px;
}

header > .mediumfontbox
{
z-index: 2;
}

header > #overlay1 
{
   z-index:1;
   height: inherit;
}

header > #overlay2 
{
    z-index:1;
    height: inherit;
}

header > #overlay3
{
    z-index:1;
    height: inherit;
}
```

fontboxes.css

```
.smallfontbox 
{
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}


.mediumfontbox 
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.bigfontbox 
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.font
{
    color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 32px;

}
```

layout.css

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

#overlay1
{
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.125;
    width: 100%;
}

#overlay2
{
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.125;
    width: 100%;
}

#overlay3
{
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.125;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Sorry, posted it before i was able to share it,
The other css files are not used in my index.html; 
I only included the ones that the base website uses. 
The img doesn't really matter, if you want to try it out just take an example image :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running in the header of your file, before anything is rendered in the body. Try moving your script to the end of your document body.

Answer (score 0):

- The style value for `top` should be a string with a unit - for example `'125px'`.
- `getElementById` is a function of `document`.
- `onload` doesn't apply to `div`. Put it on `body`.

```css
#mediumfontbox {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <script>
    function adjust() {
      document.getElementById("mediumfontbox").style.top = '125px';
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="adjust()">

  <div id="mediumfontbox">
    Inspirational quote
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, i'll try that.
(PS: I am a sys admin; I am sorry for being nooby with these kind of topics :P)